# How to Change number to date postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am using postgres Version

```
version
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 
(Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.880
```

I have a column `dept_dt` stored as integer but running this query results in error:
sample data :

```
dept_dt

20141008
20141008
20141008
20141008
20141008
20141008
20141008
20141121
20141121
20141121
```

> ERROR: Data value "dept_dt" has invalid format Execution time: 1.21s
>        1 statement failed

On running this query:

```
select top 10 dept_dt ,to_date('dept_dt','YYYYMMDD') 
FROM dept_dt_t 
where dept_dt is not null;
```

Comment: Could there be a row with an invalid date, like `20149999`, or more subtly, `20140229`?  (2014 is not a leap year)

Comment: "top 10" doesn't look like PostgreSQL, more like SQL Server or some other brand of database.

Comment: I have a `0` row,could be thats the issue ? @Andomar

Comment: That would definitely be an issue.  Can you filter it out with `where dept_dt <> '0'` ?  Or select a value like `select case when dept_dt <> '0' then to_date('dept_dt','YYYYMMDD') else 'n/a' end from dept_dt_t`

Comment: Amazon Redshift is not PostgreSQL, it's only based on pg. You need to tag properly.

Comment: I would guess that the correct syntax is to_date(dept_dt,'YYYYMMDD') to use the field dept_dt, now you are trying to convert "to_date" to a date...

Answer (score 1):

Based on [`TO_DATE()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html?tag=duckduckgo-d-20) documentation:

> TO_DATE (string, format)
>
> **string**    String to be converted.
>
> **format**   A string literal that
>   defines the format of the string to be converted, in terms of its date
>   parts. For a list of valid formats, see Datetime format strings.

needs `string` where your column `dept_dt stored` integer.

Cast to string first:

```
SELECT TOP 10 dept_dt ,TO_DATE(CAST(dept_dt AS CHAR(8)),'YYYYMMDD')
FROM dept_dt_t 
WHERE dept_dt IS NOT NULL;
```